# Wordpress user login auth query as core php

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, where is the user login query, like what we do in our php core as:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from user where username= 'this' and password = 'this'");
```

Which file/code run on admin login?  I need to check my custom permission for an admin, sub admin, superadmin, such as:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from user where username= 'this' and password = 'this' and login_auth = 'true'");
```

Comment: hi, there are pre-defined roles such author,admin,editor you can use those what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way to do what you want to accomplish.  WordPress does not handle users in the way you are trying to use them.

The good news is that there are methods you can use to add parameters to users, and then to check those parameters, all utilizing the built-in WP functionality.  THIS would be the way you could add additional custom permissions, and still work within the WordPress structure.

Check out this article:
[Adding and Using Custom User Profile Fields](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields)

By the way, do not ever modify core WP files.  Doing so makes it impossible to update WordPress.  They release regular updates that often include security enhancements, so you definitely want to keep WordPress updated.